# Excel Circular reference problem without real circular reference

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have this complex file which have no circular reference at all, but it keeps warning me about them. I have tried everything i know and still not able to find how to fix it.

I deleted every single formula, i deleted all the sheets, and still same error. I tried deleting macros, and everything.

I have uploaded the file here with macro

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BB7-mKWFwNabiqT-bFXjW7TJHlY0d7Jd/view?usp=sharing

and in case you dont feel safe about macro, here is without the macro
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xX0Fa5mWBeNZ4n8SVz1YBvPooQhFKYj9/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112399645615818920675&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Any `xlsheethidden` sheets? Or any `xlsheetveryhidden` sheets?

Comment: none hidden sheets @bugdrown

Answer (score 0):

In the menu **File**, **Options** you can alter the behaviour in case of circular references. Once you have done this, you can open your file and search for the circular references without problem:

[image]

Comment: but This should not be ideal right? should not be better to find why is giving me this circular refference? tks for your time!!